# Can we always find a basis so that two linearly independent vectors becomes orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

**Problem:** Given the linearly independent set of vectors $\{\binom{2}{1}, \binom{2}{2}\}$, can we pick a basis for these vectors which makes the set orthogonal?

**Question:** Do I interpret this as asking if we can represent each vector in terms of a new basis so that the resulting coordinate vectors, with respect to that new basis, are now orthogonal?

Or do I interpret this as asking could these vectors be the coordinate vectors for some other basis so that they become orthogonal?  In other words, is there some basis in which these two vectors are the coordinate vectors for and that they are now orthogonal?

Edit: This is a homework question on change-of-basis vectors.  It is verbatim.  It's a Yes or No type question, and we are supposed to provide justification.  I think my main confusion comes in how to interpret what they are looking for as I mention in my question.

Comment: Apply the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

Comment: "A basis for these vectors" is unclear. Usually a basis is for a vector space.

Comment: @JMoravitz I tried.  That gives the orthogonal set $\{\binom{2}{1}, \binom{-2/5}{4/5}\}$. But then under my first interpretation of this problem, I would need that the coordinate vectors, with respect to this orthogonal set I found by Gram-Schmidt, to be orthogonal and they are not.

Comment: @aschepler Under the assumption that I am in the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ with real scalars.

Comment: If what you wanted was an orthonormal basis of the span of the set, Gram-Schmidt will do it, but is more complicated than necessary. The span is $\mathbb{R}^2$, so $(1,0), (0,1)$ makes a great orthonormal basis. If you want to define a new inner product so that $\langle (2,1), (2,2) \rangle = 0$, that's easy: use those two vectors as the basis, and they're automatically perpendicular in the inner product defined with respect to that basis.

Comment: @JMoravitz The vector $\binom{2}{1}$ becomes the vector $\binom{1}{0}$ with respect to the Gram-Schmidt orthogonal set, and the vector $\binom{-2/5}{4/5}$ becomes $\binom{6/5}{1}$.  These two coordinate vectors are not orthogonal to each other.

Comment: @aschepler So actually define the inner product  as $\langle (2,1), (2,2) \rangle = 0$ and then show that this is indeed a valid inner product?

Comment: @aschepler Oh, taking the original two vectors themselves as the basis gives the coordinate vectors with respect to themselves as $\binom{1}{0}$ and $\binom{0}{1}$.  Clever.